# slick slider стрелки внутри слайда

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

Как сделать что бы стрелки слайдера были внутри слайда и вместе с ним пролистывались?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы имеете ввиду "А можно ли стандартными средствами плагина поместить элементы управления в **КАЖДУЮ** карточку", то ответ - нет. Однако вы можете реализовать это отредактировав исходный код (естественно этого делать не стоит) или же поступить иначе:

скрыть стрелочки, которые генерирует плагин, из виду (`visibility: hidden`); после этого для каждого слайда создать свои собственные и обрабатывать на них событие клика; в обработчике вы обращаетесь к DOM-элементу соответствующей стрелочки слайдера и вызываете на ней метод click().

Это, как мне кажется, более мене простой и логичный вариант. Можно стрелкам slick slider задать такую же анимацию, как и у самих слайдов, и тогда будет аллюзия того, что кнопки навигации двигаются вместе с карточками.

Однако с точки зрения использования это не удобно - пользователь хочет быстренько полистать картинки, а ему приходится ждать пока уедет, а потом приедет кнопка - это же не удобно. Я бы на вашем месте отказался от такого решения.